# Store procedure used with jdbc, can't get it working

Tags: java, mysql

I have been trying it for like 2 hours now and I can't get this working so I need your help.

I'm making a JavaFX application which uses stored procedures to make changes in a MySQL database. Well I need an store procedure which receives 6 parameters and depending if the register exists or not, update or insert.

I'm getting syntax error it doesn't care what i try. This is my store procedure now it says there is an error near UPDATE:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `contactos`.`sp_guardar1` (IN foto varchar(100), IN nombres varchar(45), IN correo varchar(45), IN telf varchar(45), IN estado INT)

BEGIN

DECLARE IdAmi INT;

SET IdAmi = IdAmigo;


IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM amigo WHERE IdAmigo = IdAmi)

            UPDATE amigo SET foto = foto, nombres = nombres, correo = correo, telf = telf, estado = estado WHERE IdAmigo = @IdAmi
    ELSE
            INSERT INTO amigo(foto, nombres, correo, telf, estado) VALUES( foto, nombres, correo, telf, estado )
END
```

Please help :)

Comment: add does this SP even work outside of Java?

Answer (score 1):

Your `IF` statement is missing the keyword `THEN`. It should be

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM amigo WHERE IdAmigo = IdAmi)
THEN  --<-- correction here
  UPDATE amigo
    SET foto = foto, nombres = nombres, correo = correo,
      telf = telf, estado = estado
    WHERE IdAmigo = @IdAmi
ELSE
  INSERT INTO amigo(foto, nombres, correo, telf, estado)
    VALUES( foto, nombres, correo, telf, estado )
END
```